# Exchange 1000s digit with 10s digit (C)

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I am trying to switch for example: input 54321.987, then 4 and 2 should switch, so output would be 52341.987. 54321.777 should become 52341.777. If it is 2345.777 it should be 4325.777. Anything less than that I do not care about. But if it was like 888886543.777 only the second and fourth numbers should be switch from the most right part before the comma. So it would become 888884563.777

So as LearningC suggested, I am trying to exchange only the 1000s digit with the 10s digit.

But whatever I try, I get errors. I can't pass the errors. How shall I do this?

What I have so far that actually works is just this:

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        double x;
        scanf("%lf", &x);

        double tens = ((int) (x / 10)) % 10;
        double thousands = ((int) (x / 1000)) % 10;

        printf("%09.3f", x += (tens - thousands) * 990.0);
        return 0;
    }
```

The code above now works.

Comment: But whatever I try, I get errors. I can't pass the errors., so I have tried various things but get errors, I've took them out of the above code because it was not relevant

Comment: The simplest way is to use `snprintf()` and some character manipulation on the formatted string.  What should be the output for the input 123.456 — is it 143.256?  What should be the output for 1234.567 — is it 1432.567? What should be the output for 987654.321 — is it 967854.321?

Comment: @F4LLCON means you want to interchange the digits in 10th and 1000th position only?

Comment: @LearningC that is exactly what I am trying to do yes

Comment: So you want to switch the 10s digit and the 1000s digit; funny — I was counting from the left end, not backwards from the decimal point, because…well, because that's the normal way of counting.  It also demonstrates why more than one example helps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, that's not a normal way to count, because from the decimal point, the comma, you can always count the second and fourth digit, but if you count from the left to the right, and it has for example 10 digits more, the second and fourth place from the left would significantly change. If you want to sum up digits, for example 97873 + 89374678, you are not summing them from left to right, but from right to left. Because.. well, that's just the way it is

Comment: @F4LLCON Nevertheless, it is ambiguous, so clarifying is often helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to determine these digits.

You can do so with

```
double tens = ((int)(x / 10)) % 10;
double thousands = ((int)(x / 1000)) % 10;
```

which enables you to do

```
x = x - (tens * 10.0) - (thousands * 1000.0) + (tens * 1000.0) + (thousands * 10.0);
```

which subtracts them at their original place and re-adds them in a swapped way.

You can optimize this to

```
x = x + tens * (1000.0 - 10.0) - thousands * (1000.0 - 10.0);
```

and, again, this to

```
x += (tens - thousands) * 990.0;
```

Comment: Note: This method fails for `x > 10*INT_MAX`.  Suggest `int thousands = ((int) fmod(x, 10000)) / 1000;`

Answer (score 1):

Using string manipulation:

```
char string[20];

snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%09.3f", x);
char *dot = strchr(string, '.');
assert(dot != 0 && dot > string + 4);
char old_4 = dot[-4];
char old_2 = dot[-2];
dot[-2] = old_4;
dot[-4] = old_2;

/* If you need a float back */
sscanf(string, "%lf", &x);
```

Using arithmetic manipulation:

```
double frac_part;
double int_part;

frac_part = modf(x, &int_part);

long value = int_part;
int  dig_2 = (int_part / 10) % 10;
int  dig_4 = (int_part / 1000) % 1000;
assert(dig_4 != 0);
value -= 10 * dig_2 + 1000 * dig_4;
value += 10 * dig_4 + 1000 * dig_2;
int_part = value;
x = int_part + frac_part;
```

Neither sequence of operations is minimal, but they are fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this:

```
double swapDigits(double in)
{
    return in + ((int)(in / 10) % 10 - (int)(in / 1000) % 10) * 990.0;
}
```